# Disable browser 'paint' until *something* is loaded

Tags: javascript, browser

I hope this is a question I can ask here ; I know there are rules.

This site https://mylisting.27collective.net/my-city/ (a demo site for a wordpress theme) has a spinner which is visible during page changes.

It seems to me that the browser is restricted from clearing the screen, or beginning to paint the new screen, until some event occurs. The result is that the spinner works beautifully and even on a slow connection the user never sees so much as a flicker between pages.

Can anyone shed any light on how this is achieved?

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: There are no page changes. Thats the trick ;)

Comment: Hmmmm, not sure thats true. If I visit that link and click on a link then I go to a new url eg. https://mylisting.27collective.net/my-city/category/nightlife/

Answer (score 0):

This is actually pretty simple. There's a div (main-loader) that sits over the top of the site (the spinner), when the DOM ready event fires, the loader div fades out....

Looking at the code of that page it's simply the below...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
    e(".main-loader").fadeOut(750), // <-- This is the loader div
    // .....
}
```

Comment: But if I set my chrome tools to 'low end mobile' and click on a link, the new page of course takes an age to load but I never see a white screen. The original page remains visible UNTIL the new page has loaded sufficiently for the spinner itself to load.

Comment: Not sure but my answer is how that is displayed. Dom ready takes longer to load due to the throttling i guess

Comment: The spinner is an illusion. Ita doing nothing clever just displaying on page change amd fading out on dom ready. Take a look at the js and you will see

Comment: I appreciate your comments, so thank you. I think my question more relates to what happens when a user clicks on a link on a page that has already fully loaded and which has already hidden the spinner. Its the transition from that point to the displaying of the next page - that moment in between - that I'm interested in. I've seen lots of spinners in action of course but very very often you will catch a white screen in the middle, particularly with a poor connection. `This site doesn't suffer from that.

Comment: I see your point, but the magic is down to an inline style of the loader at parse time of the html, which is pretty instant (code below), then once dom ready kicks in it gets hidden via the code in my answer.
<div class="loader-bg main-loader" style="background-color: rgba(29, 35, 41, 0.98);">

Comment: Yes!!! Thats it alright I'd say. Well done, very clever of you. Thanks a million. Not sure if I should mark your answer above as correct because really the inline style is the answer isn't it?